# Выровнять по центру текст в JTextArea

Tags: java, текст, выравнивание

Здравствуйте!
Я создал окно с табличным менеджером размещения. Хочу, чтобы текст в каждой ячейке таблицы был расположен по центру, однако применение методов выравнивания не решает проблемы. Подскажите пожалуйста, как выровнять текст по вертикали и по горизонтали

```
JFrame infoWindow = new JFrame("Окно");
infoWindow.setVisible(true);
infoWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
JPanel grid = new JPanel();
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, 2, 10, 10);
grid.setLayout(layout);

JTextArea area1 = new JTextArea("Текст первой ячейки", 20, 20);
area1.setLineWrap(true);
area1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
area1.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
grid.add(area1);
...
JTextArea area4 = new JTextArea("Текст четвертой ячейки", 20, 20);
area4.setLineWrap(true);
area4.setWrapStyleWord(true);
area4.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
grid.add(area4);

infoWindow.setContentPane(grid);
```

Comment: в JTextArea это нельзя сделать

Comment: Тогда откуда в этом классе методы setAlignmentX и setAlignmentY?

Comment: Хорошо, подскажите пожалуйста, какой класс использовать, чтобы можно было выравнивать текст по центру и по вертикали и по горизонтали?

Comment: эти методы из предка - **JComponent**. это общий предок для все компонент.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В JTextArea так сделать нельзя, но можно использовать JTextPane с аттрибутами

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws BadLocationException{
    SimpleAttributeSet attrs;
    StyledDocument doc;

    JFrame infoWindow = new JFrame("Окно");
    infoWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    infoWindow.setSize(200, 200);
    JPanel grid = new JPanel();
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, 2, 10, 10);
    grid.setLayout(layout);

    JTextPane area1 = new JTextPane();
    area1.setEditorKit(new MyEditorKit());
    attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setAlignment(attrs,StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
    doc = (StyledDocument)area1.getDocument();
    doc.insertString(0,"Текст первой ячейки",attrs);
    doc.setParagraphAttributes(0,doc.getLength()-1,attrs,false);
    grid.add(area1);

    /* ... */

    JTextPane area4 = new JTextPane();
    area4.setEditorKit(new MyEditorKit());
    attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setAlignment(attrs,StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
    doc = (StyledDocument)area4.getDocument();
    doc.insertString(0,"Текст четвёртой ячейки",attrs);
    doc.setParagraphAttributes(0,doc.getLength()-1,attrs,false);
    grid.add(area4);

    infoWindow.setContentPane(grid);
    infoWindow.setVisible(true);
}

class MyEditorKit extends StyledEditorKit {

    public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
        return new StyledViewFactory();
    }

    static class StyledViewFactory implements ViewFactory {

        public View create(Element elem) {
            String kind = elem.getName();
            if (kind != null) {
                if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ContentElementName)) {

                    return new LabelView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName)) {
                    return new ParagraphView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.SectionElementName)) {

                    return new CenteredBoxView(elem, View.Y_AXIS);
                } else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.ComponentElementName)) {
                    return new ComponentView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.IconElementName)) {

                    return new IconView(elem);
                }
            }

            return new LabelView(elem);
        }

    }
}

class CenteredBoxView extends BoxView {
    public CenteredBoxView(Element elem, int axis) {

        super(elem,axis);
    }
    protected void layoutMajorAxis(int targetSpan, int axis, int[] offsets, int[] spans) {

        super.layoutMajorAxis(targetSpan,axis,offsets,spans);
        int textBlockHeight = 0;
        int offset = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {

            textBlockHeight = spans[i];
        }
        offset = (targetSpan - textBlockHeight) / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < offsets.length; i++) {
            offsets[i] += offset;
        }

    }
}
```

*Ответ был взят с англоязычного [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213045/centering-text-in-a-jtextarea-or-jtextpane-horizontal-text-alignment)*